# Mahapps using VS Styles throws IOException

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, mahapps.metro

I'm using Mahapps Tabcontrol in my WPF application. When I use the default styling it works well, if I try to use the VS Styles in the App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="UI.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:UI.ViewModel"
         xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UI"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Teal.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseDark.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/VS/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/VS/Colors.xaml" />
            <!-- Icons -->
            <ResourceDictionary x:Name="IconsDictionary" Source="Resources/Dictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <system:Double x:Key="WindowTitleFontSize">16</system:Double>
        <FontFamily x:Key="HeaderFontFamily">Segoe UI</FontFamily>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="MainLocator"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

...it throws an error: IOException: **Cannot locate resource 'styles/vs/controls.xaml'**.

If I remove the VS/Styles reference from the App.xaml the application compiles.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/1476

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction, the link lead to another link where I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix!

First, removed the VS/Styles from the App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            
            <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Teal.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseDark.xaml" />
            <!-- Icons -->
            <ResourceDictionary x:Name="IconsDictionary" Source="Resources/Dictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Second, moved it to the MainWindow.xaml under Window.Resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/VS/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/VS/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Found the fix here [resources are not defined in 'Styles\VS\Colors.xaml'](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/1572)